# What is "base" in a Ruby Module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

With the

```
def self.included(base)
end
```

hook one can get access to the including class from inside the `included` hook. That far I know Modules. But am I not passing `base` as a parameter to the hook? Doesn't this mean that it should also be available inside the whole `Module` as some kind of Module-variable and pre-exist the hook in the Module?

It obviously isn't defined as a class-variable (`Module.class_variables`), instance-variable (`Module.instance_variables`) or Constant as deducible from the fact that it's lowercase.

What is the `base` argument, then? Is it only "summoned into existence" when you pass it as argument to a Module hook?

@spickermann

```
2.6.0 :001 > module ConcernModule
2.6.0 :002?>   extend ActiveSupport::Concern
2.6.0 :003?>   included(base) do
2.6.0 :004 >       puts "base is #{base}"
2.6.0 :005?>     end
2.6.0 :006?>   end


Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):1
        1: from (irb):3:in `<module:ConcernModule>'
NameError (undefined local variable or method `base' for ConcernModule:Module)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at the [docs for `included`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-included)?

Comment: The docs say that ```included``` in Concerns does also have a ```base``` parameter, but I get an error message, when I try to invoke it like ```included(base) do ...```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Concern/included

Comment: NameError (undefined local variable or method `base' for ConcernModule:Module). Thanks.

Comment: Please post your concern, how you include your concern into the class and the error message you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Module#included`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-included) is *a callback* that is called from [`Module#include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-include) explicitly passing `self` as a parameter to the method.